# Pulling elements in order based on first element using key array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I'm looking for a vectorized approach for the following problem:

Suppose I have two arrays, one with a bunch of non-contiguous ids in the first column and some data in the remaining columns, and a second array suggesting which datalines I need to pull:

```
data_array = np.array([[101,4],[102,7],[201,2],[203,9],[403,12]])
key_array = np.array([101,403,201])
```

The output must stay in the order given by the key_array, leading to the following:

```
output_array = np.array([[101,4],[403,12],[201,2]])
```

I can easily do this through a list comprehension:

```
output_array = np.array([data_array[i==data_array[:,0]][0] for i in key_array])
```

but this is not a vectorized solution.  Using the numpy *isin()* is very close to working, but does not preserve the given order:

```
data_array[np.isin(data_array[:,0],key_array)]

#[[101   4]
# [201   2] not the order given by the key_array!
# [403  12]]
```

I tried making the above work by some use of *argsort()*, haven't been able to get anything working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `data_array[np.isin(data_array[:,0],key_array)]`?

Comment: This doesn't work because the order I gave in the key array is not preserved.  I'll edit the post to make this more clear.

Comment: Are all keys from `key_array` promised to be in that first column of `data_array`?

Comment: Yes, the key_array is initially determined based on the data_array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
s = data_array[:,0].argsort()
out = data_array[s[np.searchsorted(data_array[:,0],key_array,sorter=s)]]
```

If the first column of `data_array` is already sorted, simplifies to one-liner -

```
out = data_array[np.searchsorted(data_array[:,0],key_array)]
```